# MySQL performance tuning related connection

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, linux, connections

I am running openstack cloud and it use mysql database which is `MariaDB 10.1.30`

I am sometime seeing connection reset from multiple clients, to trying to find out what is going on in database, I am seeing following connection related status but want to make sure what expert advice here, should i need to increase `max_connection` in mysql?

I have 64GB memory on server but also other components running on servers so trying to avoid overcommit memory, what is the relation between threads and connection count?

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE '%onn%';
+-----------------------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                                 | Value    |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------+
| Aborted_connects                              | 5951     |
| Connection_errors_accept                      | 0        |
| Connection_errors_internal                    | 0        |
| Connection_errors_max_connections             | 406      |
| Connection_errors_peer_address                | 0        |
| Connection_errors_select                      | 0        |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap                     | 0        |
| Connections                                   | 23430967 |
| Max_used_connections                          | 1601     |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost | 0        |
| Slave_connections                             | 0        |
| Slaves_connected                              | 0        |
| Ssl_client_connects                           | 0        |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates                      | 0        |
| Ssl_finished_connects                         | 0        |
| Threads_connected                             | 1284     |
| wsrep_connected                               | ON       |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Threads

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE '%Threads%';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Delayed_insert_threads  | 0     |
| Slow_launch_threads     | 0     |
| Threadpool_idle_threads | 0     |
| Threadpool_threads      | 0     |
| Threads_cached          | 47    |
| Threads_connected       | 1284  |
| Threads_created         | 86815 |
| Threads_running         | 1     |
+-------------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here is my my.cfg file.

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"


[mysqld_safe]
socket = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
nice = 0
log_error = /var/log/mysql_logs/galera_server_error.log


[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8


[mysqld]
user = mysql
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
bind-address = ::
server-id = 200

# LOGGING #
log-queries-not-using-indexes = 0
slow-query-log = 0
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql_logs/mysql-slow.log
log_error = /var/log/mysql_logs/galera_server_error.log
log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/mariadb-bin
log-bin-index = /var/lib/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
expire-logs-days = 7
log_slave_updates = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet = 16M
max-connect-errors = 1000000

# NOTE: If galera_max_connections is not configured by user, the number of max
# connections is defined by ( host_vcpus * 100 ) with a capping value of 1600.
# This value is the lowest integer based on the ansible facts gathered from
# every galera node.
# Computing the connections value using the lowest denominator maintains
# cluster integrity by not attempting to over commit to a less capable machine.
# These are the computed max_connections based on the cluster data
# [1600, 1600, 1600]
max_connections = 1600

wait_timeout = 3600

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size = 32M
max-heap-table-size = 32M
query-cache-type = 0
query-cache-size = 0M
thread-cache-size = 50
open-files-limit = 65535
table-definition-cache = 4096
table-open-cache = 10240

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-file-size = 1024M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size = 4096M

# Depending on number of cores and disk sub
innodb-read-io-threads = 4
innodb-write-io-threads = 4
innodb-doublewrite = 1
innodb-log-buffer-size = 128M
innodb-buffer-pool-instances = 8
innodb-log-files-in-group = 2
innodb-thread-concurrency = 64

# avoid statistics update when doing e.g show tables
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet = 16M


!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

## UPDATE - 1

After increase `max_connection` from 1600 to 3200 fix my connection abort issue look like

[image]

Comment: Other aspects of tuning, won't solve your problem however might help. thread-cache-size is too small because of the high Threads_created (hard to tell significance without uptime). innodb_buffer_pool_size of 4G seems small on a 64G machine. Even with a large amount of connection its probably too small. But really, solve the slow queries.

Comment: I have checked `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and hardly its in use, showing `5%` only in used of total

Comment: With threads_connected at 1,284 it is likely we need to see 10 seconds of your General Log for analysis.  This is a symptom of absence of connection close when processing has completed for the connection.

Comment: Many `STATUS` values are useless without `Uptime`.  For more analysis, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your setting of max_connections is 1600 and max_used_connections is 1601, your 0.1% connection related issues is probably exceeding this limit.

The first initial reaction is to increase max_connections, however the underlying problem is that to get to this amount of connections, your queries are usually too slow.

Enable your slow query log and start asking questions about your slow queries.

Comment: Or your clients are failing to disconnect??

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=256  # from 50 to reduce threads_created
max_connect_errors=10  # from 1 million, no need to be liberal with Hackers/Crackers
innodb_thread_concurrency=0  # from 64 to allow system to auto calculate load
```

Disclaimer: I am the content author of web site mentioned in my profile, Network profile and can provide additional performance tuning suggestions.

Comment: @Satish Were any of the April 5, 2019 suggestions applied?  Date applied?  Thank

Comment: @satish Could you recap how the suggested Global Variables changed your instance performance attributes?  Thanks