# Separate login during `Too many connections` in AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

AWS-RDS does not provide any user with SUPER privilege. As a result, '**too many connections**' are made, even the dba is locked out. Nobody can login and kill any sleeping connection. Apart from taking pre-emptive actions to avoid 'too many connections' like creating an event scheduler to kill sleeping connections, how to deal with the error?

Comment: What are the client(s)?  Apache?  Tomcat?  ...?

Comment: Have you considered simply increasing the number of allowed connections?

Comment: Fix the slow queries, like [this non-AWS answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233986/mysql-performance-tuning-related-connection/234000#234000). A server can support 10 connection x 100ms queries in a second, however if the query time is reduced to 5ms, 200 connections can be supported (roughly and slightly hand-wavy).

Comment: @RickJames : Tomcat.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : Yes, we have already increased the number of allowed connections.  I am looking for a way to login to RDS when the server is giving 'too many connections' error

Comment: @danblack We are working on it. I am looking for a way to login to RDS when the server is giving 'too many connections' error.

Comment: @SubrataDas Have you looked into database connection pooling? It is supposed to address this type of situation.